# Using C#, how do I inject a return statement into a method?

Tags: c#, validation, model, data-annotations

Thanks for looking, I realize the question is a bit odd.  Here is what I am hoping to accomplish:

## What I have

I am using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to validate a model that has been posted from a web page.  I have already partially abstracted the necessary code into a shared method:

```
public static string Create_Widget(WidgetModel postedWidget)
        {
            //Validate the model
            var errors = HelperMethods.Validate(postedWidget);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
            {
                return errors;
            }

            //Do other stuff

        }
```

And the helper method:

```
 public static string Validate<T>(T entity)
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext(entity, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, context, results);

            return string.Join(",", results.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage));
        }
```

## What I would like to have

What I really want to do is just have an extension method to validate my model with out adding an `if statement` beneath it for the conditional return:

```
public static string Create_Widget(WidgetModel postedWidget)
            {
                //Validate the model
                postedWidget.Validate(); //Automatically returns error string if errors.

                //Do other stuff

            }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just throw an exception of validation fails.

Comment: throw an exception and catch it somewhere you want to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, but ultimately I need to return a comma-delimited string of errors as the code is currently doing.  Can I do this by simply throwing an exception?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt If the exception contains that data, and the caller catches it and provides that data, sure.

Comment: @Servy--Ok, thanks.  I am going to give that a go. . .

Comment: I think it would be more readable if you just returned a `string`.

Comment: What happens to the returned string ? You want to store that string somewhere right, since the return type of method Validate is string.

Comment: @kai--That string is what ends up getting returned to my view.  I parse it and display as an error list to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from the comments above, I produced the following code which does exactly as I wanted:

## The Extension Method:

```
public static void Validate<T>(this T entity)
        {
            var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var result = "";

            try
            {
                var context = new ValidationContext(entity, null, null);
                Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, context, errors, true);
                result = (errors.Any()) ? string.Join(",", errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)) : "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                throw new Exception(result);
            }
        }
```

## Usage

Assuming you have a valid model with data validation annotations, all you need is this:

```
widgetModel.Validate();
```

If one or more properties within your model don't clear validation, a comma delimited list of errors is returned.  In my case, I am using AngularJS in the view so I can use `.error()` to catch failed api calls and use the list of errors in the view.